# Compiling in Eclipse with gcc's -lpthread and -lrt set

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am currently trying to use Eclipse to develop some code that I've been doing in a text editor in C.

I am currently under Linux, compiling it with GCC with the following arguments:

```
gcc -o SO SO.c -lpthread -lrt
```

I've tried adding `"-lpthread -lrt"` to Eclipse's "C/C++ Build"->"Discovery Options"-> "Compiler Invocation Arguments" but it seems of no avail.

I also tried on "C/C++ Build"->"Discovery Options"-> "Settings" but that doesn't seem to do it, too.

How may I override Eclipse's GCC command line arguments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the project properties, go to : C/C++ Build --> Settings. 
Then "Tool Settings", select "Libraries" under "Linker". 
You can add all your project libraries there (without the "-l"). Also in the lower part, you can add custom path to search libraries.

Answer (score 2):

`-lpthread` and `-lrt` are passed to the linker, not the compiler.  There should be some way in Library to add these as new libraries.