# Adding -lrt option when compiling with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I am trying to compile a program that uses the function `clock_gettime`. The man page on Ubuntu says it has to be compiled with `-lrt` option.

If I issue the command

```
gcc myprogram.c -lrt
```

my program compiles fine.

Now how do I add the option `-lrt` to Eclipse. I already tried adding `-lrt` to:

> GCC Compiler->Miscellaneous->Other flags and GCC C Linker->libraries

This question is posted here - however the answer does not seem to help me.
[Compiling in Eclipse with gcc's -lpthread and -lrt set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201129/compiling-in-eclipse-with-gccs-lpthread-and-lrt-set)

Comment: In the accepted answer of the question you linked, did you pay attention to 'without the "-l"'?

Comment: @Fred Larson. Yes you are right. I should have read more carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a long time since I last used eclipse, but there should be a + button in the section you mentioned (GCC compiler -> etc -> libraries). Just click on it and write rt, then click on it again and write pthread, that should be it (to add both libraries, of course).

EDIT: nevermind, the post you mentioned says it should be in the Build section, but you'll see there's a + button, thats for sure.

Comment: that worked thanks! ... i just didnt know it was rt, I have been trying -lrt..So it's really -l rt right?

Comment: -l is the parameter saying that you're linking to librt (rt is the actual name, but lib is always in front of any lib's name). Remember to accept the answer.

Comment: sorry i didnt know that .. new to the forum.. thanks again. I just accepted your answer.

Comment: Its ok, that's all theres to it. Good luck with your project.