# sem_open doesn't work with Ubuntu : undefined reference to `sem_open'

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, pipe, shared-memory

Given this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 256
int main()
{
    key_t key;
    char *virtualaddr;
    sem_t *get, *put;
    int shmid;

   const char* messageOne = "Hello world , I'm child number 1\n";
   const char* messageTwo = "Hello world , I'm child number 2\n";

   char buf[BUF_SIZE];

   key = ftok("anyfile",'R');

  shmid = shmget(key,1024,0644|IPC_CREAT);
...
...
shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I get from eclipse `undefined reference to sem_open` .

I've check with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916881/sem-open-error-undefined-reference-to-sem-open-on-linux-ubuntu-10-10) since this question is very similar to mine , but didn't understand exactly where is my mistake ,

Can you please explain where do I need to fix it / add another compilation command (if this is indeed the case) ?

Much appreciated

Comment: Please read the second answer to that question carefully. You're not doing what it says you should be doing.

Comment: I don't know how eclipse works, so here is a question: When do you get the error? Is it shown in the editor just as you type in sem_open, or only shows up when/compiling? How do you compile?

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Only when I compile it .

Comment: possible duplicate of [sem_open() error: "undefined reference to sem_open()" on linux (Ubuntu 10.10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916881/sem-open-error-undefined-reference-to-sem-open-on-linux-ubuntu-10-10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `-lpthread` when compiling. This is used by the linker, to link your binary against the library.

*The other answers already cover how to do this on the command line.*

**To do this in Eclipse, you need to follow the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4201129/274261):**

> In the project properties, go to : C/C++ Build --> Settings. Then
>   "Tool Settings", select "Libraries" under "Linker". You can add all
>   your project libraries there (without the "-l"). Also in the lower
>   part, you can add custom path to search libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is very annoying for the Eclipse users , if you write the command in `terminal` each time ... and there are more downsides . Anyway ,thanks ! +10 for this if I could :)

Answer (score 1):

When linking, you have to add the flag `-pthread` or `-lrt` to the command line. It's right there in the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open).

Answer (score 1):

As it is written in the first answer in the question you linked, you nedd to compile it in this way:

`gcc source.c -lpthread`

`-lrt` or `-pthread` will do the same.