# Posix Semaphore compilation error in Makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, semaphore

This is my makefile:

```
program : program.o
          gcc -o program program.o
program.o : program.c library.h
            gcc -c program.c
```

In "library.h" I've got the headers, but I have a problem with the semaphores.
It says "undefined reference to sem_open , sem_post, sem_wait. . ."

Comment: possible duplicate of [sem\_open doesn't work with Ubuntu : undefined reference to \`sem\_open'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500879/sem-open-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-undefined-reference-to-sem-open) - please at least type your error message in Google before posting here. The first four results for "undefined reference to sem_open" are Stack Overflow posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link to the pthread library - `libpthread`.  Try changing your link command to

```
program : program.o
          gcc -pthread -o program program.o
```